# One admin - 100 users - simplicity, solution? (iOs app will read this files)

Tags: google-drive-api

I have to develop an ios application. On the first side, one admin will manage some files (pdf, movie) and on the other side, near 100 person will communicate with this files in a "read only" mode.

Is there a DropBox solution?

I thought that i will create only one account, and work with the only folder app which DropBox recommend, but DropBox may not accept this system?
I thought that each person will have to create an account and the app will read a shared folder by the admin, but we don't really need to create 100 account... and this will use the "full dropBox mode app" which DropBox not recommend.

Sorry for my english.
I Prefer use DropBox or google drive than a server because of theirs ergonomics and simplicity, but maybe there is no solution...
Is google drive an alternative solution?

PS : the app will not be available on the appStore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't talk for Dropbox but as far as Google Drive is concerned:

What you could do if you don't want the 100 users to have a Google account is to share the file publicly and then the 100 users can simply read the file. Since it is shared publicly they will not have to authorize.

However if you want to keep control on the authorization of the file and not share it publicly  the 100 users will have to have google accounts. Then you could simply share the file to these users and they will have access to it. You can set the sharing to be read-only if you want.